# How do I add tabs in Github pages?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I'm trying to add in our docs that is running on Github pages code examples in tabs like this:

[image]

I found a plugin that seems like it can do the job [jekyll-tabs](https://github.com/Ovski4/jekyll-tabs), but I can't install it and looking at [Github docs](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/setting-up-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll/about-github-pages-and-jekyll#plugins) it seems like it only allows a closed list of plugins.

Is there a way to make this plugin run on Github pages?
Or, is there another way to add tabs?